# Get count of unique element and element as well from array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array,

```
$servArray = [AC Service,AC Installation,AC Service, AC Installation];
```

So I want to print,

```
AC Service = 2;
AC Installation = 2
```

How do I print both the values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for that. Use an object as accumulator which will have array items as keys and values as their count. And then use `forEach()` on `Object.entrries` to iterate through them keys and values.

```js
const $servArray = ['AC Service','AC Installation','AC Service', 'AC Installation'];

const getCount = (arr) => arr.reduce((ac,a) => {
  ac[a] = ac[a] + 1 || 1;
  return ac;
},{})

const res = getCount($servArray)

Object.entries(res).forEach(([key,value]) => console.log(`${key} = ${value}`))
```

Comment: Ho to get keys and value individual from

Comment: @GauravJadhav Use `Object.entires()` to print the values. I have updated the answer check it

Answer (score 0):

We can use es6 `map` function and iterate the array and assign the expected result in declared object.

```
const $servArray = ['AC Service','AC Installation','AC Service', 'AC Installation'];
const counts = {};
$servArray.map(x => counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1);
console.log(counts);
```